# module 'matplotlib' has no attribute '_get_configdir'

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

i am using python 3.7.1 and recently when im trying to run matlplotlib it isnt working. im getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute '_get_configdir'
```

i tried using "matplotlib.use("Agg")" and i still get the same error.
i tried upgrading my matlpotlib version in anacond using this command 
`pip install --upgrade matplotlib` and i get this error.

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/c0/69e3f695d7384012e90be1e16570c08953baae00fd98094179ef87c7d5a2/matplotlib-3.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11 in c:\users\josh\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.16.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\josh\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\josh\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\josh\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\user\josh\conda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in c:\users\josh\conda\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in c:\users\josh\conda\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (40.6.3)
chances 0.1.6 has requirement matplotlib==2.2.3, but you'll have matplotlib 3.1.1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\josh\\conda\\Lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\ft2font.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

can anyone guide me in this?
i dont know what to do. thank you.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Seem you have a package `chances 0.1.6` installed that is incompatible with newer matplotlib versions. You may uninstall that package in case it's not needed. Or you install matplotlib 2.2.3.

Comment: If you're using the Anaconda distribution, create a new environment with `conda create` specifying the packages and versions you want to use. It is possible to use `pip` with conda but I think trying to upgrade things with pip is likely to lead to broken dependencies.